# How register events in yii2

Tags: yii2

I would like to trigger some events in my model, if I register my events via app->on in `index.php` then I don't receive required `$event->data` from event object.

How register my events handlers, so when I call trigger it will call correct function with event object.

Code sample:

```
namespace app\modules\Product\models\Product;

class Product extends Entity\Entity {
    public static function tableName() {
       return 'sometable';
    }

    public function afterFind() {
       parent::afterFind();
       $event = new yii\base\Event;
       $event->data = $this;

        $this->trigger('calculatePrice', $event);
    }

}

namespace app\modules\PriceRules\models;

class PriceRules extends yii\base\Model {
    public static function calculatePrice($event) {
        $entity = $event->data;
    }
}

//somehow register events
```

Comment: You should read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html#configuration-format. And sorry but do you really need to use events just for setting price ?

Answer (score 1):

Add in `Product` in method `init` this code:

```
class Product extends Entity\Entity {
  public function init()
    {
        $this->on('calculatePrice', ['app\modules\PriceRules\models\PriceRules', 'calculatePrice']);        
    }
   ...
}
```

See doc - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I placed `PriceRules` module inside `bootstrap` and added this code there:

```
yii\base\Event::on(Product::className(), 'calculatePrice', [PriceRulesEvent::className(), 'calculatePrice']);
```